# React Native - Connect two pickers

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, react-native, picker

How I can connected two pickers in react native.

For example user has first_name and last_name. When the user click on first picker and select first_name automatically change the value in second picker last_name.

For example we have user with first_name = 'John' and last_name = 'Deep'. When the user click on first picker John automatically in second picker set value to Deep.

I don't use library for picker, but I use library for local database: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage

Answer (score 0):

you can call a function with `onValueChange` everytime picker changed

```
<Picker
   selectedValue={this.state.firsname}
   style={{height: 50, width: 100}}
   onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
    this.yourfunc(itemValue, itemIndex)
   }>
 <Picker.Item label="John" value="John" />
 <Picker.Item label="abc" value="abc" />
</Picker>

<Picker
   selectedValue={this.state.lastname}
   style={{height: 50, width: 100}}>
 <Picker.Item label="Deep" value="Deep" />
</Picker>

//set your selectedValue to the state where you save the value

....

yourfunc = (val, index) => {
   //doing some stuff to change another picker
   let lastname = //get lastname from val
   //and then this.setState lastname
}
```

Official [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker#onvaluechange)